# Range data in multiple column transpose into single row in vba

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I am trying to transpose multiple data in multiple columns into a single row at the new worksheet. My original data would show as below

Before

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
  1  |   2  |  3
  1  |   2  |  3
  1  |   2  |  3
```

After

```
Row1   1  |   1  |  1 |  2  |   2  |  2  | 3  |  3  |  3
```

Can someone help me with vba code that can transpose from original worksheet to new worksheet.Thank !

Comment: Please, post what you have already tried. This is not a "freelancer finder" type website.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you data is in A:C on a sheet named `data`.  Put this in the first cell:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(data!$A$1:INDEX(data!$A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,data!$A:$A)),COLUMN(A:A)),IFERROR(INDEX(data!$B$1:INDEX(data!$B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,data!$A:$A)),COLUMN(A:A)-COUNT(data!$A:$A)),INDEX(data!$C$1:INDEX(data!$C:$C,MATCH(1E+99,data!$A:$A)),COLUMN(A:A)-COUNT(data!$A:$B)))),"")
```

Then copy to the right.

[image]